# Given 3 non-negative integers, n, m, and a, what is the fastest way to find the smallest x such that (x*a) % n = m % n?

Tags: python, numbers, theory, modulo

Preferably, Id like a solution with time complexity O(1), O(log(n)), or O(sqrt(n)), since all the numbers are going to be pretty big.

Thanks in advance!

Note:
a < n
m < n

Answer (score 1):

I'd use:

```
(m * pow(a,-1,n) ) % n
```

We want x, such that x = m/a, which is the same as m * 1/a. Python can do modular inverses automatically if you have the most recent version. :-)

Per the comment below, here's my modular Inverse function:

```
def findModularInverse(m,n) -> int:
    """Find m' such that m*m' === 1 (mod n)"""
    if "HCF" not in globals(): HCF = __import__("math").gcd
    assert HCF(m,n) == 1, "Not coprime."
    s,sx,sy,t,tx,ty = m,1,0,n,0,1
    while True:
        q,r = s//t, s % t 
        u,ux,uy = r, sx-q*tx, sy-q*ty
        #print("{} = {}x + {}y".format(u,ux,uy))
        if r == 0: a,b = tx,ty; break
        else: s,sx,sy,t,tx,ty = t,tx,ty,u,ux,uy; del q,r,u,ux,uy
    return a%n
```

The poor thing has been deprecated and sent to the code retirement home.

Comment: Ooh, they added modular inverse support. This does assume that `a` is relatively prime to `n`, though. It needs adjustment to handle the not-relatively-prime case. (Also, if you're on Python <3.8, you'll have to implement the extended Euclidean algorithm yourself or pull in a dependency for it.)